# Python regex matching based on specific pattern

Tags: python, regex

Matching the string, If only specific pattern found ,Else whole string should be rejected.

For instance here is the string, It should match the string if only a-z,A-Z,0-9, :(colon), .(point), ;(semicolon) ,- (hyphen), "(double inverted), (,) Comma, [ ] square brackets, ( ) parenthesis, \ (back slash) were present in that string & has to accept that string, like given below it has to accept the string1

```
string1 = "This is nandakishor's messAGe'\; [to]test(897185) "few(1 -\ 2)" regexs"
```

If other things like $,%,^,&,@,# were present in the string, Then that whole string has to be rejected. Like given below it has to reject the string2

```
string2 = "This is nandakishor's messAGe'\; [to]test(89718$#!&*^!5) "few(1 -\ 2)" regexs"
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re

string1 = '''This is nandakishor's messAGe'\; [to]test(897185) "few(1 -\ 2)" regexs'''
string2 = '''This is nandakishor's messAGe'\; [to]test(89718$#!&*^!5) "few(1 -\ 2)" regexs'''

def validateString(strVal):
    return re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9:;\.,\-\",\[\]\(\)\\\s*\']", "", strVal) == strVal

print(validateString(string1))
print(validateString(string2))
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
import re

string1 = '''This is nandakishor's messAGe'\; [to]test(897185) "few(1 -\ 2)" regexs'''
string2 = '''This is nandakishor's messAGe'\; [to]test(89718$#!&*^!5) "few(1 -\ 2)" regexs'''

def validate_string(str_to_validate):
    match_pattern1 = r'[a-zA-Z,():\[\];.\']'
    match_pattern2 = '[$%^&@#]'

    return re.search(match_pattern1, str_to_validate) and not re.search(match_pattern2, str_to_validate)

print(validate_string(string1))
print(validate_string(string2))
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
```

Comment: match_pattern1 can be simply check if there are non space characters; like this: '\S+'